# how to get user id on facebook request dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What i want to do is get the request ID and insert to my database. My request dialog is run well, but the problem is I cannot get 'TO' user id http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ , but I still cannot get the request user ID.

here is my coding:

```
         function newInvite(){
            //var user_ids = document.getElementsByName("user_ids")[0].value;
           FB.ui({ 
                    method : 'apprequests',
                    title: 'X-MATCH',
                    message: 'Come join US now, having fun here',                       
            },                      
            function getMultipleRequests(requestIds) {
              FB.api('', {"ids": requestIds }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
              });
            }                   
            );
        }
```

any solution on this?

million thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enable request 2.0 efficient?

If you have enabled, you can get the user id easily as the response like this

```
{
    request: ‘request_id’
    to:[array of user_ids]
}
```

In your callback function, you can use

`response.request` to get the request ID

`response.to` to get the array of user ids

And notice that if you use request 2.0, the request ID format will like this

```
<request_object_id>_<user_id>
```

If you doesn't enable it, then you can only get the array of request ids and you need to make another api call to get the user id

**Edited:**

```
FB.ui({
        method : "apprequests",
        title : "your title",
        message : "your msg"
      },
      function(response)  {
          var receiverIDs;
          if (response.request)  {
              var receiverIDs = response.to;  // receiverIDs is an array holding all user ids
          }
      }
);
```

Then you can use the array "receiverIDs" for further process

For example I sent a request to user id with id "1234", "5678"

The response will like this:

```
{
    request: ‘1234567890’   // example,
    to:['1234', '5678'] 
}
```

In request 2.0, the full request id will look like this

```
1234567890_1234
1234567890_5678
```

Caution: FB doc tell you to manage and delete the request yourself, if you using request 2.0,
remember to delete the id like the above, if you directly delete the request '123456789', all the full request ID  with this prefix will be deleted.

==================================================================

If you haven't enable request 2.0, follow the code on the doc page to see how to get the user id by making a api call

```
function getMultipleRequests(requestIds) {
  FB.api('', {"ids": requestIds }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

The response format for these methods is as follows:

```
{
   "id": "[request_id]",
   "application": {
      "name": "[Application Name]",
      "id": "[Application ID]"
   },
   "to": {
      "name": "[Recipient User Name]",
      "id": "[Recipient User ID]"
   },
   "from": {
      "name": "[Sender User ID]",
      "id": "[Sender User Name]"
   },
   "message": "[Request Message]",
   "created_time": "2011-09-12T23:08:47+0000"
}
```

you can implement the callback of api call and getting who is the receiver by `response.to.id`

Comment: thanks hanon, but how to I in callback get the user id? isn't something like this?

function requestCallback(response) {
      top.location.href="REDIRECT_URL?req="+response.to;
}

Comment: I update my answer, see how to get the id array.

If you want to track the data of the request
then use FB.api("/requestID", callback) to get the data.

Remember the format of the id

Comment: thanks a lot, i get the request ID, but how to i know this request ID is belong to which user id? i need the user id for inserting to my db, in addition, I had tested your code, it's work, but once is send request to my friend, my friend opened my request it display white blank page,the link it shown like this:http://apps.facebook.com/christmas_testing/?request_ids=132802000161969 ,  how to I solve this?

Comment: It seems your requestID is not using request 2.0 , see the updated answer above.

For the blank page, are you redirecting the user to another page if  the url contains a request id? check it carefully.

Comment: i had edit my code on the top,take a look, but still cannot get the ID, sorry im new in facebook graph api, that why keeping asking for the answer

Comment: Have you enable request 2.0? The code you updated are wrong, you should not get the id like this

Comment: OK, then use this code

FB.ui({
        method : "apprequests",
        title : "your title",
        message : "your msg"
      },
      function(response)  {
          var receiverIDs;
          if (response.request)  {
              var receiverIDs = response.to;  // receiverIDs is an array holding all user ids
          }
      }
);

and print out the receiverIDs and you should get the user id