# Facebook FriendsList window not opening in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the `FB.UI()` JavaScript SDK to get the selected friends id, when the user selects friends from Friendslist request dialog window.
The selected friends id is passed to a handler file.

The above situation is working fine in Firefox, that is, I am able to get the friends Id, but the same is not working in Internet Explorer 8.

In IE8, I am getting the error below when I click the button to open the friends request dialog.

> API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by
>   the application.

I had given the `redirect_uri` also but I'm not getting the friends id.

The code is given below:

```
function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {
       alert("sendRequestToManyRecipients");
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
              appId  : '',        
           display: 'popup',           
          message: 'My Group'
        }, requestCallback);       
      }

 function requestCallback(response) {
        getMultipleRequests(response.request_ids);
      }

var friend=new Array();
      var sfriend="";
      function getMultipleRequests(request_ids)
      {   
            if (response && request_ids)
             {
                    var ids = request_ids;                    
                    var _batch = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) 
                    {              
            _batch.push({ "method": "get", "relative_url":ids[i] });
                    }
                    if (_batch.length > 0) 
                    {
                        FB.api('/', 'POST', { batch: _batch }, function (res) 
                        {                           
                            for (var j = 0; j < res.length; j++) 
                            {
                                body = res[j].body;
                                var myObject = eval('(' + body + ')');
                                friendID = myObject.to.id;                               
                                friend[j]=friendID.toString();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
                showfriends();
            }


    function showfriends()
            {                
                 for (var i = 0; i < friend.length; i++)
                 {
                    sfriend=sfriend+","+friend[i].toString();
                 }              
                if(sfriend != null)
                {                    
                    window.open("Friends.ashx?id="+sfriend,'WinName','width=900,height=500,left=200,top=200'); }               

            }
```

I'm searching for a solution but I am not able to find the correct one.
Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you want to get the friend id that the user have sent in the apprequest dialog?

Consider using request 2.0 efficient, which can help you get the ids without calling another api after sending the request

I have answered a similar question before, please take a look:
[how to get user id on facebook request dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251769/how-to-get-user-id-on-facebook-request-dialog/8252336#8252336)

updated: 2011-11-29

For your ref, I use this code before for a project on fb app, which works on both IE8, Firefox 7, chrome 15

```
FB.ui({
    method : "apprequests",
    title : "title",
    message : "messafe!!", 
    display : "iframe"
    },
    inviteCallback
);              

function inviteCallback(response)  {
//  Requests 2.0 Efficient
//  {
//      request: ‘request_id’
//      to:[array of user_ids]
//  }
    if (response.request)  {
        var receiverIDs = response.to;
        document.inviteForm.receivers.value = receiverIDs.join(",");
        document.inviteForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hanon!!Thanks for Your reply.You are right.I want to get the friends id for which the user has sent the apprequest dialog.The above code what i had posted was working fine(i.e. I can able to get the friends id) in Mozilla.But in IE 8 the above code is not working.

Comment: If you want to get the id for further process, enable request 2.0 will help you to save  a lot. Take a look to my link in the answer. For your code, I think the problem is the code in getMultipleRequests, from FB api, you can simply call this FB.api('', {"ids": requestIds }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }); and that's done!

Comment: Thanks for reply Hanon.The main problem for me is that the friends request dialog window is not opening in IE 8(but successfully opening in Mozilla) for the above code i had used.If friends dialog itself is not opened i cannot able to proceed to further steps like getting the userid.I had implemented your suggested code also but I'm not getting the desired result.Can you please provide the code such that the friends dialog window will open both in IE and Mozilla.

Comment: I use my code and it work for both chrome, ie8 and firefox, is IE8 block the popup? try to use 'iframe' instead of 'popup' to see if it is ok

Comment: Can u just post your code Hanon.I used display:'iframe'.but its showing error window.
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Comment: Still I'm not able to get the selected Friends ID in IE8 for request dialog.

Comment: Can anyone help me how to sort this problem  in IE.

Comment: Maybe you can try to prompt the friend request without any further process first to see if it can work in IE8.

Comment: The Friends request dialog itself is not opening in IE8.